# Delphi, Override Custom controls setCaption

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-7

i have a custom control, 
with the Ancestor being another custom control, 
who's Ancestor is a TPanel;
i.e.

```
TNotMyCustomControl = class(Tpanel);

TMyCustomControl    = class(TNotMyCustomControl);
```

Is i possible to react when the Caption is being set (run time or design time), and still have the changed passed to the Ancestor controls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible. Just add a `CMTextChanged` message handler to your custom `TPanel`:

```
type
  TMyPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    procedure CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
  end;

{ ... }

procedure TMyPanel.CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('caption has been changed');
end;
```